# How to restrict editing `disabled` attribute of HTML button from HTML source code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have one Button like this:

```
<input type="button" class="clsinvoice" value=" " id="btnInvoice" 
style="display: inline;" onclick="OpenInvoice();" disabled>
```

which I have set as disabled by default. After some operation, it gets enabled.

The problem I am facing is that, anyone who knows basic HTML code can edit the 'disabled' attribute and can use the button, and so on.

Is there any way to restrict the editing of that Attribute???

Comment: What does `c#` tag has to do with this?

Comment: This question may be helpful https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/88779/how-to-prevent-user-from-removing-disabled-attribute-and-manually-editing-role

Comment: anyway you can disable the shortcut key for inspect elements if you want or mouse right clicking.

Comment: @VijunavVastivch please don't do that. That's just security by obscurity. It doesn't help against those that want to circumvent it.

Comment: Dont you worry @andreasnico  i aggreed to your answer.

Comment: @VijunavVastivch that's good to hear :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No there is not. You must never trust what comes from the client (i.e the browser, as a request to the server etc). You must check this server side to be sure that the operation is allowed.

Comment: This is correct. You can't stop the user from changing anything on the client side. They can do whatever they want. All you can do is validate their actions on the server side.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, just disabling html element is quite vulnerable to what you have just said.
What I usually do is to restrict both html and javscript function to be run on the front-end, as well as the methods at the server-side